# Vue dynamic v-model generating extra array item with null value

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, inertiajs, laravel-jetstream

I am working on inertia laravel to update data from Vue inline table input,

this is jet-stream input field component.

```
<jet-input type="text" v-model="inlineEdit.partner[item.id]"/>
```

***item.id*** is my database increment id.

```
   data() {
        return {
            inlineEdit: this.$inertia.form({
                partner: [],
            }),
        }
    },
    methods: {
        updateInline() {
            this.inlineEdit.put(route('codes.update'))
        }
    }
```

and this is the result when i try to update.

```
array:6 [▼
  0 => null
  1 => null
  2 => null
  3 => null
  4 => null
  5 => "123"
]
```

5 is the actual ***item.id*** but don't know why it is showing 0 to 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably if you set fifth element in the array, then it automatically expanded to required size with null elements on missing positions.

Probably you want to use associative array (js object, `{}`) instead of array (`[]`)

For this just replace the initial value of `partner` to empty object

```
            inlineEdit: this.$inertia.form({
                partner: {}, // <-- there
            }),
```

Comment: But how can  i use object here ?
<jet-input type="text" v-model="inlineEdit.partner[item.id]"/>
item.id has the dynamic value.

Comment: Updated my answer. You still can access value by string key in object using square brackets

Comment: Maybe you will need to cast int index to string. For example `<jet-input type="text" v-model="inlineEdit.partner[item.id+""]"/>`